# PHP Email form don't go to the location provided on header

Tags: php, header, sendmail

I've got an php file with the html form (`contacts.php`) who calls after submit another php file (`contact_en.php`), as showned below:

```
    <?php
        $to = "xxxx@xxxx.xx".","."xxxx@xxxx.xx";
        $nome = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['message'];
        $subject = "Contato do website EN";
        $headers = "From: xxxx@xxxx.xx";
        $body = "From: $nome \n\n Email: $email \n\n Message: $mensagem";
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        if($sent) {
            header("Location:../en/success.php");
        } else {
            print "A system error has occurred, please try again later.";
        }
    ?>
```

The issue that I have is that the code sends the email, but instead of going to `success.php`, it stays at `contact_en.php` (blank page).

I'm a newbie on php, so how do I fix it?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output buffering to solve this problem)

Comment: try using an absolute URI (http://...) and adding `exit;` after `header()`

Comment: @HussyBorad, thanks for your reply but did not worked, i've tried the following: header("Location:http://xxx.xxx.xxx/en/success.php"); exit; (in different lines), and stays the same, I've also tried all in the same line as follows: header("Location:http://xxx.xxx.xxx/en/success.php") exit; and gives me the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT) in...

Comment: In your last code, there's a missing semicolon after the closing parenthesis

Comment: Please add **error_reporting(E_ALL)** on the top of the page inside php code. I am sure there must be some error or warning on the page, as a result page is blank, Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting a correct `Location`-header you have to follow some rules. Depending on the browser it might work without following these, but it's safer:

1. Use absolute URIs with scheme, domain, port, path, etc `http://www.domain.com/en/success.php`
2. A space between the colon and the text: `header("Location: http://...");`
3. Add `exit;` after `header()`

So in the end, use this (maybe the path has to be adjusted):

```
if($sent) {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/en/success.php");
    exit;
} else {
    print "A system error has occurred, please try again later.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reeno, unfortunately it didn't worked for me, the problem is with the headers, after followed the advise from Amit Shah, it gives me a warning: Warning: Cannot modify header information. For now I will use the solution from @HussyBorad, but I've to study better the php headers. Nevertheless your information was usefull. Thanks again.

Comment: The warning `Cannot modify header information` says that there is some text output before you call `header`. If any character is sent to the browser, it doesn't work

Comment: This is the complete warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/page-contact_en.php:1) in /xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/page-contact_en.php on line 14. Sorry for my ignorance but I can't understand where I'm sending characters to the browser? I've cleaned all white spaces.

Comment: What is in line 14 of page-contact_en.php?

Comment: After your advice: header("Location:http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/en/success.php"); with http://

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the error. Output is starting in line 1 (`page-contact_en.php:1`). So maybe there's some whitespace before the starting `<?php`

Comment: According to the error message there is some :) There may be an unprintable character in front of <?php which your editor isn't showing. Delete the whole line and add it again

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but did not work, so I changed the editor from Komodo to Notepad++ and saved the document as UTF-8 without DOM, and it worked. Thanks again for your tip.

Answer (score -1):

If echo statement use before header so not redirect page. so for that you can also try this. echo `<script>window.location='url'</script>`

Comment: Thanks @HussyBorad. It was a solution for my problem, but the more strange I've other website with same code and don't have this issues.

Comment: ob_start();
       header("Location: https://sitename.com/success.php");
       exit();

Comment: sometime it depend on hosting server.

Comment: The both websites are hosted in the same hosting company, and have the same service. More weird...